# Using AJAX to delete/edit items from a list

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of tickets that are being displayed using a for loop that traverses through my ViewModel.  So far I have been using Ajax.BeginForm but I want to change this so I can use JQUERY and AJAX.  How do I make it so I can access the correct values from JQUERY.  I know it has something to do with the naming schema but can't remember how to do it (havent done it since I took my web development class a while ago).  Below is the code for my table/ticket list output.

```
@foreach (var ticket in Model.ticket)
        {
                <tr class="viewTickTr">
                    <td class="viewTickTd">
                        <label id="ticketId">@ticket.id</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="viewTickTd">
                        <label id="dateCreated">@ticket.dateCreated</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="viewTickTd">
                        <label id="supportStaffId">@ticket.supportStaffID</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="viewTickTd">
                        <label id="empId">@ticket.empId</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="viewTickTd"></td>
                    <td class="viewTickTd">
                        <label id="categoryId">@ticket.categoryId</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="viewTickTd">
                        <label id="severityId">@ticket.severityId</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="viewTickTd">
                        <label id="statusId">@ticket.statusId</label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="viewTickTd">
                        <input type="button" value="Edit" class="ticketEditButt" />
                    </td>
                    <td class="viewTickTd">
                        <input type="button" value="Delete" class="ticketDeleteButt" id="deleteTickBtn" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to pass the value of `ticket.id` to your controllers `Delete(int id)` method?

Comment: I made all the outputs labels.  If i click edit for one record, I want it to call JQUERY on click of edit button and then use ajax in jquery to send the data to my controller.

Comment: Why would you do that for an edit method? You only need to pass the ticket ID. And what is your intention when you click the edit button? Are you trying to edit the ticket in a popup form on the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would decorate your buttons with a `data-id` attribute and populate it with the ticket id, when you click the button grab the id from the attribute and pass it along with your ajax call.

```
<input type="button" data-id="@ticket.id" value="Delete" class="ticketDeleteButt" />
```

*notice I removed the `id="deleteTickBtn"`, having multiple items with the same id will cause issues in IE. You will want to remove these from all your rows*

in jQuery to get the id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".ticketDeleteButt").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    //make ajax call here
  }
}
```

you could so something similar for your edit, except redirect the user to the Edit page in your button click

Comment: For the edit action, may as well skip ajax and just render a link `@Html.ActionLink("Edit" "Edit", new { id = ticket.id })` but not clear what OP wants to actually do with the edit

Comment: Thank you @Anthony Shaw that worked great for my delete.

Comment: I would use action link but I want to make it so when the edit button is clicked, below that ticket, text boxes with the appropriate values will be displayed and then can be changed and saved

Comment: @user3255899, in that case, add a `data-id="@ticket.id"` to the edit button, call an an ajax function to return a partial view that contains a form to edit the item and add the partial to the DOM. You would need handles the submit button to remove the form and update the values in the table. And remove all the `id` attributes from the labels (its invalid html) and they should not be `label` anyway. _The label tag defines a label for an input element._

Answer (score 0):

You can store values in another attibute:

```
<td class="viewTickTd">
    <label id="ticketId" val="@ticket.id">@ticket.id</label>
</td>
```

And then get it with jquery:

```
$(".viewTickTd #ticketId").attr("val");
```

Using this as a guideline, you can get all other attributes, iterate over items to get every id,...

Comment: this would return every id in the table, no matter which one was clicked on

Comment: A `<label>` tag does not have a `val` attribute! And it would not work anyway even if you did it correctly with `data-id="@ticket.id"` since OP is rendering invalid html with all the duplicate ID's so it would only ever return the first one anyway

Comment: technically, jquery would allow the val to work, but it will still select every one (and it is still invalid html,you're right). I also noted the duplicate id's in my answer below

Comment: @AnthonyShaw, It would select everyone but only return the value of the first one.

Comment: No: ticketId is an id and it is unique.

And as I said, that's the functionality to get the value, which was the main question of OP, not to trigger the `click` event nor anything like that.

Comment: @Joanvo, OP is creating multiple `label` elements in a `foreach` with `id="ticketId` so they are **not** unique. `$(".viewTickTd #ticketId")` returns all of them and then `.attr(val)` returns the value of the first one so this would not work. [Refer docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: Please, keep in mind two things: 1. My sample code is a reference on how to do it, OP should modify it according to his code. 2. Id in html elements MUST be unique

Answer (score 0):

you can bind a function to the html element,and pass the id as parameter.like this

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="delItem(id)"/>
```

on js file,define delItem function:

```
function delItem(id){
   //use ajax to post
}
```